# How to find commits not having a particular word in commit message?

Tags: git

I want to list down all commits where a particular word (for example - 'reviewed by') is missing in commit message . How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're in a normal UNIX environment:

```
git log --oneline | grep -v "reviewed by"
```

The -v switch of grep inverts the match, so it'll return all lines that don't contain "reviewed by" in this case.

You can also search using regular expressions with

```
git log --oneline --grep=REGEXHERE
```

But in your case it's probably simpler to use the grep commandline tool with the -v switch instead of messing with regular expressions.

Comment: git log --oneline | grep -v "reviewed by" returns lines not containing reviewed by. For example, if I've commit message as `_Line 1_ Summary of commit. _Line 2_Detail exlanation of what commit is supposed to do. _Line 3_ reviewed by - Abc ` - returns first 2 line

Comment: I think this command will do - ' git log --invert-grep --grep="Reviewed" --pretty=format:"%cn, %h, %f, %cd" '

Comment: In recent versions of git, the --oneline switch is shorthand for "--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit".  If it's showing three lines for you, it's likely that you're using an older version of git from before that command line switch was implemented.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 0):

`git log` + `grep` with an exclusion pattern is the simplest way I can think of:

```
git log --pretty=oneline | grep -v "reviewed by"
```

git log will output all your commits.

`--pretty=oneline` will display the commit id and commit message in one line.

`grep` will match the pattern in his standard input, with the `-v` flag it will exclude the lines that match.